# How to set IIS Logging to best fit this scenario

Tags: iis-7, logging, performance-monitoring

I need to monitor a IIS 7 App Pool (WCF is running on it) and I would like to read messages like:

1. Request A Received.
2. Pool is down.
3. Starting Pool.
4. Request B Received.
5. Pool going up.
6. Request C Received.
7. Pool going up.
8. Pool UP.
9. Response A sent.
10. Response B sent.
11. Response C sent.
12. etc...

**Background**
I'm receiving alot of performance complaints that the application is slow and i noticed that it's in "sync" with a regular pool refresh that we do... When we tested it out and decided on the time-interval, this was not happening and for couple of weeks running at full steam we got like 2 calls, now we're getting 30 plus each day... I believe that the pool is taking too long to "get up"...

**Edit1:**
My expectation is that upon a Recycle, the pool should be up and running in less than 30 seconds. Right now i want to determine how long it's taking. If i can get a more accurate info such as I/O from reading the dll and other intrinsic operations would be great

Comment: Why is your load balancer sending requests to a server where the application is down/has not finished starting?  That's what you need to fix.

Comment: @GregAskew there's no load balancer here... the whole application is hosted on a single server...

Comment: That's the problem that should be corrected.  What is your expectation?  That it start faster?  If so, seems obvious to me that the amount of time required to start would be provided.  It seems unlikely that the issue is with IIS or the operating system, but an application defect.

Comment: @GregAskew check edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using logging... specifically the application start and shutdown... it gave me the data i needed in the end with a fair enough accuracy